# Can anybody help me with my `for loops` using numpy vstack?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vstack

Say I have about 640 numpy arrays to stack vertically. Each array is of the size (66, 1). Doing this manually like this:

```
A = np.vstack((Ne['State_1_inc'], Ne['State_2_inc'], Ne['State_3_inc'], Ne['State_4_inc'], ..., Ne['State_640_inc']))
```

would obviously take a long time and is very time consuming. The end result would have A the size (66,640). Anybody know if I could do a `for loop` that will pass in all of my 640 states so I can build my matrix? New to programming here, thanks!

Comment: You mean `np.vstack([Ne['State_%s_inc' % i] for i in range(1, 641)])`?

Comment: Maybe.. lemme try that.

Comment: I think because our modulo % is inside the string python is reading the object as Ne['State_%s_inc'] where all of my states are written in `Ne['State_n_inc']` where n=(1,640].

Comment: It's string formatting: `'State_%s_inc' % i`. Make sure you include `% i` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use all the elements of your dictionary:

```
Ne = {1: [1,2,3], 2: [4,5,6]}
np.vstack(list(Ne.values()))
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Else you can use a dict comprehension:

```
np.vstack([Nef[f'State_{i+1}_inc'] for i in range(640)])
```

Comment: This looks promising. But I'm still getting an error. <ipython-input-12-5f8740525b62> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 A = np.vstack(([Ne['State_{i+1}_complete'] for i in range(640)]))

KeyError: 'State_{i+1}_complete'

Comment: Maybe because the variable `i` in the for loop is inside a string that causing some problems?

Comment: I forgot the `f` of the f-string, check the update